# Pull access denied in docker run command

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-build, docker-pull

I have the below code to build an image

```
docker build -t provisioner-builder:latest -f images/provisioner/Dockerfile.builder .
```

Right after this build command I have this line

```
docker run provisioner-builder:latest  /bin/true
```

The `docker run` command always throws this error in jenkins

```
06:23:44 Successfully tagged provisioner-builder:latest
06:23:44 docker run provisioner-builder:latest  /bin/true
06:23:45 docker: Error response from daemon: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for provisioner-builder, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
06:23:45 See 'docker run --help'.
```

SO out of 15 runs in jenkins, the above step fails at-least 10-11 times. I get lucky very rarely. I am not trying to pull image as the image is already present in local [I tested by doing a `docker images` right after the build command and the image was locally present].

I dont understand why this command fails most of the times.

Comment: the docker build and docker run commands are run in the same Jenkins node?

Comment: Yes, On the same node @IgnacioMillán